# Filtering issue for showing selected item

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to develop an example of filter items by category. Following block of code shows list of item by category filter.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="order_id">Filter by Category</label>
    <select class="form-control m-b" name="category" ng-model="item.searchString">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option ng-repeat="category in item.itemscategory" value="{{category.name}}">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="chat-user" ng-repeat="iteme in item.items | filter:item.filterSearch"
 ng-class="{'text-navy':$first == true}">

        <a id="{{iteme.id}}" 
        href="" ng-click="item.selectitem(iteme)">{{iteme.name}}</a>

</div>
```

If I select any item in the list and change category to filter them I want by default that item will selected if present in list or select first item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

In Js you can set:

```
$scope.firstItemInTheList= item.itemscategory[0];
```

To save the first item, also set it to `ng-model` of `select` tag.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="order_id">Filter by Category</label>
<select class="form-control m-b" name="category" ng-model="firstItemInTheList">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option ng-repeat="category in item.itemscategory" value="{{category.name}}">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="chat-user" ng-repeat="iteme in item.items | filter:firstItemInTheList"
 ng-class="{'text-navy':$first == true}">

    <a id="{{iteme.id}}" href="" ng-click="item.selectitem(iteme)">{{iteme.name}}</a>

</div>
```

If you are not choose any option from the `select`, the filter using this

```
$scope.firstItemInTheList= item.itemscategory[0];
```

to filter.